# Kendo UI with CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp

I am developing an appliction in CakePHP 2.x. and want to use Kendo UI. How can I do that and use it in my app? Can anyone tell me if it is possible and if so how?

My Controller:

```
class ClientDetailsController extends AppController {

    var $name = "ClientDetails";

    public $helpers = array('js');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');


    function index(){

        $this->loadModel('User');

        $userdata = $this->User->find('all');

        $this->set('user',$userdata);

    }
}
```

My View:

```
<h1> User in Index Pages of the Client Details .... </h1>
<?php 

//pr($user);

echo $this->Html->link('Personal Detail',array('controller'=>'ClientDetails','action'=>'add'));
?>

<div id="calendar" ></div>

<div id="info" >  </div>

&nbsp;
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link('Room Details ',array('controller'=>'RoomDetails','action'=>'index'));

?>
```

Comment: You most significant challenges will be forms, I am currently bootstrapping my cakephp and it is a challenge, but I have learnt a lot. Begin by researching what KendoUI's required html is, then go from there. You really need to start here [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html) and keep using the helpers more, no one can give you an answer here, you just need to practise working with cakePHP html helpers more and learn how to customise them to suit your needs. You question also falls under theme layouts etc, you're question is broader than you realise.

Comment: @Anti-Fun please don't give advice on a topic that you are unsure of. It is a fairly straight forward and easy implementation. Using this is no different than jQuery.

Comment: @user1852176 yes... scold me when clearly the guy with 1 reputation who has done NO research is essentially asking things that show he didn't even read the kendoUI tutorial. It is different to jQuery because jQuery is a library and Kendo ui is a jQuery HTML5 Framework [link](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/build-apps-with-kendo-ui-mobile)

Comment: @Anti-Fun I am on a different account on my ipad. You have 60 reputation and you're talking to me about the value of it? You're blindly giving advice and said it is very difficult to implement, which it is not. Kendo, Knockout, jQuery, MooTools, etc.. are all JavaScript based and implemented the same way...via JavaScript tags. The only difference is the way the JavaScript is written, not the way it's interfaced with HTML. You're not helping and clearly don't know what you're talking about. Kendo is pre-written and formatted with no work left for you, unlike a framework. Their marketing got you

Comment: @user1852176 relax man I didn't say you have 1 rep, the original question poster has 1 rep. Also I said bootstrapping is a challenge. Big whoop I accidentally miss-linked something. Also, Judging by his question, he's going to need to gather the data from the calendar, and KendoUI isn't going to format the input element by default correctly to suit CakePHP. All I'm trying to point out is that poster hasn't demonstrated any CakePHP or KendoUI study, my knowledge about KendoUI is irrelevant. Peace...

Comment: @Anti-Fun I don't mean to be aggressive, but you're making it sound extremely difficult to implement and I don't want OP to be deterred. It is quite the opposite. It is literally no different than implementing jQuery. Just look at the [Kendo Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/from-table.html). If you can get the data to a view from a controller and make it into a table, there is no reason why you can't associate it with Kendo. Just give the table an ID and then use that ID and call the Kendo function, just like you would with datePicker or autoSelect jQuery. It's that simple.

Comment: @user1852176 I agree, from controller->view should be a breeze, I'm concerned about view->controller, KendoUI looks easy though :)

Comment: @Anti-Fun I'm not quite sure I follow your concern. All you have to do is build a form like you normally would with CakePHP form helpers. If you don't want to go that route you can always submit it asynchronously with a jQuery POST/GET request to your server then return a result and respond accordingly. [This](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Kendo, however, I have used Knockout.js extensively with CakePHP. If you've used jQuery with CakePHP, the implementation with Kendo should be no different. I took a quick look and they appear to be similar in implementation, so this is what I would do.

[Here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/introduction#using-kendo-ui) in the Kendo documentation it says to simply link the necessary files. I don't see how this is any different than jQuery. Once the files are loaded you should be able to use them.

For example, use the following code at the top of your view (but obviously with your paths)

```
<!-- Common Kendo UI Web CSS -->
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Default Kendo UI Web theme CSS -->
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Kendo UI Web combined JavaScript -->
<script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

//rest of your code here
```

Now you can use Kendo however you like. In their documentation they list the datepicker, such as

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
$(function() {
    // Initialize the Kendo DatePicker by calling the kendoDatePicker jQuery plugin
    $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
});
</script>
```

So, if you had a date input, just put put the ID of that input where "#datepicker" is listed in the example above.